# SpringBoot with Jetty Vs Core Java with OSGI Jetty

Tags: spring-boot, osgi

My project has requirement to deploy a Java Based application as an operating system Job (and not use any container). The application need to have following capabilities:-

- Scheduling
- Few HTTPS based services
- Ability to make JMX calls
- Storage: Data for last 5 to 10 minutes of transactions (not more than 600 rows X 20 columns). Something like embedded H2 or in-memory options
- Decision Tree: Something like Drools..

My manager wants to write this application as a core Java with OSGized Jetty version. I am suggesting to use Spring Boot with embedded Jetty(*which will give me ready to use capabilities for Scheduling, JMX Integration and REST Services)*.

His bend towards core Java is emerging from the requirement that this application needs to be extremely efficient, fast and self-contained. He wants to reduce dependency on any open source. I have never worked directly on OSGI but have used products coming out of it - like eclipse.

Can somebody guide how OSGI based development might benefit over SpringBoot?

Comment: Your manager is clearly smart because he values modular principles and maintainable software over the latest fad "everything including the kitchen sink" framework. For what it's worth, OSGi also supports scheduling, JMX integration and REST... as *modules* that you can either include or omit as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many people, OSGi is superfluous, because they don't see the value in being modular. Not being worth the trouble.

**Think about the application lifecycle**, more or less being plan-develop-test-deploy.

**How many developers you have?** If many, OSGi helps a lot, because being modular make the boundaries very clear. You can delegate things very easily.
If outsourcing is your thing, you can just handle the module APIs and tell them to develop against it. They will never know how the rest was implemented, no fear of secrets being leaked.

**Unit tests are so easy.** You obviously see what you can test, every else you mock/stub/spy/fake. Unit tests can be can be reused in Integration tests, of course that isn't news, but the trick is running Unit tests outside the OSGi container, and Integration tests inside. So if you decide OSGi was not worth it, your code stills works fine (unit tests being the proof).

**You can make your app a collection of modules, and every module having independent versioning and source repositories.** Makes easier to handle and find bugs. For example, the current app crashed, you find out that sub-module-1.2 is throwing errors, try with version sub-module-1.1(still bad), then version 1.0(good), bug was introduced in 1.1 (avoids bisecting the source code). Programmers don't need to be perfectly synchronized with each other if they are working in different modules.

**How do you plan to update the app?** Most frameworks are of the all-or-nothing approach, where you have to stop the world, update, then restart the app. If you make things modular, you just need to update that thing. Making the downtime very small, and sometimes even zero.

**If you need to make a big change in your app, but can't afford to refactor everything right now.** With OSGi you can run the system with both my-module-1.0 and my-module-2.0. You can even adapt my-module-1.0 to redirect calls to my-module-2.0, but that is a kind of last resort hack (just saying that you can, if you want to).

**I can do everything you say without OSGi, right?** Well, probably you can, but in the end, would be something like OSGi.

**I love the Dependency Injection of my framework.** No problem, OSGi have something like that.

**I hate Dependency Injection, it kills my app perfomance.** No problem, you can use something like `osgi.getService(MyService.class);`. The OSGi container isn't concerned about intercepting every call of your app.

OSGi is like Java++, Java plus modules.

**You can mix Spring Boot with OSGi**, can't say if this is good or bad. There are many libraries and frameworks that fit your list, many will work out-of-the-box with OSGi.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I am still not sure what kind of applications are good candidate for OSGi based effort. High level of modularity and Hot Fixing which looks like the core selling point of OSGi are not required in all projects. Most of the projects can achieve lower levels of modularity using proper packaging structure, dependency injection and few other ways. OSGi also seem to introduce its own container + Manifest file related complexities. Why not create an application using core JavaEE constructs instead ?

Comment: OSGi makes things more complex, and you are right, not everything needs it. But the manisfest complexity is of no concern if you are using Maven, there is a plugin to take care of it. The J2EE Container is way more heavy than OSGi, this is why you run apps in AppServers like Glassfish. The main difference being that J2EE is a static environment, and OSGi is a dynamic one. Of course, if you like EJB and everything that it entails, I can't argument with that. You can mix J2EE with OSGi, but there are some limitations in what you can achieve doing this.